# Error in authorizing Azure subscription for creating new Release definition

Tags: azure

I am trying to create a new Release definition for deploying one of the web app I have in Visual Studio online team project. When I authorize the Azure subscription it gives me an error:

Error(s):
Session Id: 0c6e8341-1119-44fc-a70f-5f4cef94aa80

I have a free trial subscription with Azure and my build releases stopped working because of :

*XAML build based TFS deployments are deprecated in Azure and have been replaced by DevOps tools in Visual Studio Team Services to build, test, and deploy with Continuous integration and Continuous delivery pipelines. Starting on November 1st, 2016, you will no longer be able to view your deployments from portal.azure.com and will instead need to use your visualstudio.com account portal once you have migrated to the new system. To perform the migration, you must:
Login to your Visual Studio Team Services project at visualstudio.com and add a new pipeline for continuous deployment
Return to this page and click the 'unlink' button to complete the process.
Note: Once you have 'unlinked', you will no longer be able to set up XAML build based TFS deployments. Learn more*

Thanks.

Comment: I've the same error. Any luck so far finding the problem ?

Answer (score 1):

You would need to do the following below.
1. Click on Manage button next to the Authorize button.
2. Create and Add the endpoint or XAML build Services(based on your code) for your Azure subscription
2. Point the release to that endpoint

Thanks